# Error when running command activate when re-enter the Julia project

Tags: julia

I was learning this https://mitmath.github.io/18S096SciML/lecture2/ml
But when I re-enter the `activate MLTest` command, I get

```
ERROR: syntax: extra token "MLTest" after end of expression
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I didn't `]` to activate Package manager.